# JS/jQuery > Highlight Text In Appended Imput

Tags: javascript, jquery

Upon clicking on my contextmenu menu (right-click custom menu), I have multiple cases set. The snippet below is the one set for renaming the folder (menu `li > a` value) which hides the link within the `<li>...</li>` and adds an input field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";    

    $(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).parent().hasClass('custom-menu')) {
            switch (action) {
                case 'rename-folder':

                    anchor = clicked.find('a').first();
                    anchor.before($('<input />', {
                        type: 'text',
                        value: $(anchor).text(),
                        'class': 'FolderRenaming',
                        focusout: function() {
                            $(this).siblings('a').html($(this).val()).show();
                            $(this).remove();
                            $(anchor).parent().removeClass('clicked');
                        }
                    })).hide();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }).on('keyup', 'input.rename', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            $(e.target).focusout();
        }
    });
});
```

You right click and choose the option to 'rename'. You've then got to click within this input field and either hit enter or outside of the field for the reverse to take place.

How can I make it so upon clicking to rename, the text within the appended `<input>` is highlighted and therefore focused in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `focus()` function on an element to achieve this.

By changing your `before()` call, to an `insertBefore()` call, you can chain the `focus()` method onto the element you are appending.

```
case 'rename-folder':

    anchor = clicked.find('a').first().hide();
    $('<input />', {
        type: 'text',
        value: $(anchor).text(),
        'class': 'FolderRenaming',
        focusout: function() {
            $(this).siblings('a').html($(this).val()).show();
            $(this).remove();
            $(anchor).parent().removeClass('clicked');
        }
    }).insertBefore(anchor).focus();
    break;
```

I haven't tested the above, as your code was just a snippet, but have created a basic implementation of the above here:
https://jsfiddle.net/michaelvinall/w6q09rzs/1/

Comment: Your Fiddle works nicely however upon trying to implement this into my script, nothing happens. I have tried to make a snippet of my code however it seems like I would need to fork a lot whereas on StackOverflow people just like small sections to work with.

Comment: I've just updated my question with a little more of the script. There isn't that much to it, just a lot of css and whatnot to try and get it working on a try-me-snippet.

Comment: Thanks, your issue seems to be because you're using the mousedown event instead of click.